# Hide div on click and show another div

Tags: jquery

How to show a div after another one gets hidden?

I have this div with a class name of `this-message` and after I click on `Make me disappear` button I want to show `this-message` div right after the panel gets hidden and hide `this-message` it after 4 seconds.

I looked into jQuery api but I believe this is something too specific to be there.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/fs1rnydc/1/)

This is the code I am using to hide the div:

```
$(".btn-disapear").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".panel").fadeOut(400);
});
```

Comment: are you trying something like this http://jsfiddle.net/fs1rnydc/3/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the callback for `.fadeOut()` like this:

```
$(".btn-disapear").click(function () {
    $(this).closest(".panel").fadeOut(400, function () {
        $('div.this-message').fadeIn('fast').delay(4000).fadeOut('fast')
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fs1rnydc/2/)**

When you click the button to hide your block, it shows the message div, then after four seconds hides it so it can be re-used.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$(".btn-disapear").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".panel").delay(4000).fadeOut(400);
    $("#SOMEOTHERDIV").delay(4000).fadeIn(400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/fs1rnydc/5/

```
$(".btn-disapear").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".panel").fadeOut(400, function() {
    $('.this-message').show().fadeOut(4000);
  });
});
```